# how to retain windows-like appearance of java GUI in fedora

Tags: java, windows, user-interface, netbeans, fonts

I'm using netbeans 6.7.1 on windows. I created a jframe application . When i run the same application in my fedora core OS , the appearance becomes dull , the fonts and the spacing change.. How to avoid this - as the GUI is of prime importance to my application.

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Windows look and feel on Fedora.

to [quote Sun](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html):

> Note: The GTK+ L&F will only run on
>   UNIX or Linux systems with GTK+ 2.2 or
>   later installed, while the Windows L&F
>   runs only on Windows systems. Like the
>   Java (Metal) L&F, the Motif L&F will
>   run on any platform.

You are probably currently getting the GTK+ look and feel. You have 2 other options to try, Motif and Metal. You can see how to set a different look and feel [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html).